# Case statement handling logic differently than expected

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I'm trying to assign a status based on the number of IDs using a metric. This is the query I've written (and it works):

```
select
    x.yyyy_mm_dd,
    x.prov_id,
    x.app,
    x.metric,
    x.is_100,
    case
        when ((x.is_100 = 'true') or size(collect_set(x.list)) >10) then 'implemented'
        when ((x.is_100 = 'false') and size(collect_set(x.list)) between 1 and 10) then 'first contact'
        else 'no contact'
    end as impl_status,
    size(collect_set(x.list)) as array_size,
    collect_set(x.list) as list
from(
    select
        yyyy_mm_dd,
        prov_id,
        app,
        metric,
        is_100,
        list
    from
        my_table
        lateral view explode(ids) e as list           
) x
group by
    1,2,3,4,5
```

However, the impl_status is incorrect for the second condition in the case statement. In the result set, I can see rows with is_100 = false, array_size between 1 and 10, however the impl_status ends up being 'no contact' instead of 'first contact'. I was thinking maybe between isn't inclusive but it seems to be according to the docs.

Comment: If you are using strings for `is_100`, then the string match may not be exact.

Comment: It's a boolean column with 'true' / 'false' stored rather than 1 / 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am curious if this works:

```
(case when x.is_100 or count(distinct x.list) > 10
      then 'implemented'
      when (not x.is_100) and count(x.list) > 0 
      then 'first contact'
      else 'no contact'
 end) as impl_status,
```

This should be the same logic without the string comparisons -- [here](http://www.thedatastudio.net/hive_booleans_are_too_confusing.htm) is an interesting viewpoint on booleans in Hive.  I also think that `COUNT()` is clearer than the array functionality.

Comment: You're missing an and operator in the second condition but seems to work otherwise! I agree that using distinct also looks nicer than collect_set. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have not some hidden space in the string

```
when (( trim(x.is_100) = 'false') and size(collect_set(x.list)) between 1 and 10) then 'first contact'
```

Comment: is_100 is a boolean so it can't be using with trim.